# Ошибка в Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc

Ошибка :

> DipOffline1.Models.IdentityUserLogin: : Для EntityType
>   "IdentityUserLogin" не определены ключи. Определите ключ для этого
>   EntityType.
>
> DipOffline1.Models.IdentityUserRole: : Для EntityType
>   "IdentityUserRole" не определены ключи. Определите ключ для этого
>   EntityType.
>
> IdentityUserLogins: EntityType: Набор EntitySet "IdentityUserLogins"
>   основан на типе "IdentityUserLogin", в котором не определены ключи.
>
> IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: Набор EntitySet "IdentityUserRoles"
>   основан на типе "IdentityUserRole", в котором не определены ключи.

Таблицы в бд IdentityUserLogin и IdentityUserRole есть, и ключи в них присутствуют.
В чём может быть проблема? Что проверить?

Answer (score 1):

В таблицах ключи, может быть, есть - но EF об этом не знает. По умолчанию любое свойство с именем Id является ключом сущности - у вас же, очевидно, такого свойства нет - а значит, ключ надо указать явно.

Ключ для EF надо указывать в классе сущности при помощи атрибута [`[Key]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.keyattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: не подскажите, где искать эти стандартные модели? Это стандартные таблицы из шаблона, не ужели там не указывается атрибут [Key], в других проектах все норм

Comment: Не знаю о каком шаблоне вы говорите - но, судя по пространству имен, они являются вашими классами и искать их надо в папке `Models`. Если только они не являются автогенерированным кодом - в таком случае надо разбираться уже с генератором.